# Storing data locally until application is open

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a local Sqlite DB which contains 3 table(Senior Manager, Manager,employee) & all 3 tables are interrelated.I have created 3 NSObject class for data (w.r.t Table). Now I have a Controller class where I query these tables & create object of those NSobject class
and update it. Finally I add these object to an array in that class.

Now lets say I have 3 view controllers(VC1,VC2,VC3) are there.So when I came from VC1 to VC2 I call data controller class , make query & get the array from data controller class & and show these data in 3 tableview in my VC2.So now onward I can do add/delete a new Senior Manager/Manager & Show it in different tableview in VC2.

So my Problem is when I again go back from VC2 to VC1 & again come back to VC2 I can not see the added/deleted row. Because in my viewDidLoad I am again trying to fetch my array from Data controller class so it will again show the data what ever present in DB.

Note I have a restriction , I don't want to write these add/delete operation data to any DB. So on every restart of application I have to show the default data present in DB.

Can any body help me to solve this problem? So from opening to Close of application I can maintain these data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to persist from launch to launch you will née to store it somewhere durable, a file, the DB, iCloud etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opening the database from the bundle? You can't save changes to a database in your bundle. You need to copy the database from the bundle to `Documents` and then open that database. And if you don't want to save the database between sessions, just make sure you always copy the database from the bundle to `Documents` when the app first starts up. (Generally people will copy from bundle to `Documents` only if the database doesn't already exist in `Documents`, but it sounds like you want to always copy it.)

To copy the database, you would do something like:

```
NSString *databaseName = kDatabaseName; // obviously, replace this with your database filename

NSString *documentsFolder      = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databaseDocumentPath = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
NSString *databaseBundlePath   = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:databaseName ofType:@""];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;

if (![fileManager copyItemAtPath:databaseBundlePath
                          toPath:databaseDocumentPath
                           error:&error])
    NSLog(@"Unable to copy database from '%@' to '%@': error = %@", databaseBundlePath, databaseDocumentPath, error);
```

Once you do that, you can open the database pointed to by `databaseDocumentPath`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cache the array once loaded from the DB. Here's roughly what you could do:

```
@implementation DataController

static NSMutableArray *managers;

//Note: not thread-safe
- (NSMutableArray*) managers {
    if (!managers)
      managers = loadDefaultManagers();//queries default data from sqlite db and loads array

    return managers;
}

- (void) addManager:(NSDictionary*) manager {
  [managers addObject:manager];
}
...

@end
```